# Alloy - # and Int

Tags: alloy

I am a newbie in Alloy and would like to understand how # works in connection with the restrictions on Int.
Consider the following simple model for an undirected graph with no self-loops:

```
sig Node {
 nearBy : set Node
} 
fact { 
  no iden & nearBy  // irreflexive
  ~nearBy in nearBy // symmetric
}
pred connected[nodes : set Node ] {
  all n: Node | Node in n.*nearBy 
}
pred ringTopology[nodes : set Node ] {
 connected[nodes]
 all n: nodes | #n.nearBy = 2
}
run { // (1)
  ringTopology[Node]
} for exactly 5 Node
run { // (2)
  ringTopology[Node]
} for exactly 5 Node, 5 Int
```

If I execute (1) shown above some solutions violate the #n.nearBy = 2 restriction in ringTopology, e.g. [image]
For the same example, in the evaluator I get #Node4.nearby = -4 (minus 4!).
This does not happen with (2), where I get a unique and correct solution (10-node graph with a ring topology).

Thanks,
Eduardo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which version of Alloy are you using?  It looks like you are getting that solution due to integer overflows.  The latest version of Alloy ([Alloy 4.2_2015-02-22](http://alloy.mit.edu/alloy/downloads/alloy4.2_2015-02-22.jar)) has "Prevent Overflows" option (Options -> Prevent Overflows) which should prevent that from happening.

Comment: Thanks. I was using Alloy 4.2 with  Options > Forbid Overflow set to yes and a Java 8 runtime on Fedora Linux. If I set Forbid Overflow to no, the error does not happen, is this what you meant (I was expecting the inverse) ?  I also tried the example on MacOS and the same thing happens.

Comment: There was a known bug in Alloy4.2 regarding cardinalities and overflows; in Alloy 4.2_2015-02-22 that bug is fixed; with "Prevent Overflows" set to "yes" the run (1) command should work fine (just tried with Java 8).